# my Android devices don't show up unless i restart the computer

Tags: android, adb

Once i restart the computer on bootup my device recognizes its connected and allows for debug but eventually after a day or two of locking in and out, sleeping and what not, the computer doesn't recognize any android device and you have to restart it. I tried restarting ADB and checking for devices but once the device doesn't recognize it never shows up. While its connected and not recognized it still charges via usb.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right place to post this question.

Answer (score 1):

By restarting ADB do you mean

```
adb.exe kill-server
adb.exe start-server
```

This is what I use on windows if it has trouble detecting my device (with the proper drivers installed).

Or if on Linux/Mac, I'd use

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

Comment: yes this is how you would restart ADB, and how i do it already